# Ruby on Rails: required parameters for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 5. I have model User and I want field "login" to be obligatory.

What I did:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cart

  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:login)
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. I can save new user without login.

```
irb(main):001:0> user2 = User.create

begin transaction

SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2016-08-21 11:38:17 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-21 11:38:17 UTC]]

commit transaction

=> #<User id: 4, login: nil, created_at: "2016-08-21 11:38:17", updated_at: "2016-08-21 11:38:17">
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add validation to `User` model:

```
validates :login, presence: true
```

This piece of code:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:login)
end
```

only allows login field to be set from your html form.